# Build JSON with php echo statements

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, codeigniter

Am trying to build a JSON array from a php array
This is my function in my controller

```
function latest_pheeds() {
            if($this->isLogged() == true) {
            $this->load->model('pheed_model');
            $data = $this->pheed_model->get_latest_pheeds();
            $last = end($data);
            echo "[";
                for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                    echo '{"user_id":"'.$data[$i][0]['user_id'].'",';
                    echo '"pheed_id":"'.$data[$i][0]['pheed_id'].'",';
                    echo '"pheed":"'.$data[$i][0]['pheed'].'",';
                    echo '"datetime":"'.$data[$i][0]['datetime'].'",';
                        if($i == count($data)) {
                        echo '"comments":"'.$data[$i][0]['comments'].'"}';
                        }else {
                            echo '"comments":"'.$data[$i][0]['comments'].'"},';
                        }
                    }

                echo "]";
            }
            return false;
    }
```

It returns a json array like this

```
[{"user_id":"9","pheed_id":"2","pheed":"This is my first real pheed, its got potential ","datetime":"1313188898","comments":"0"},{"user_id":"9","pheed_id":"11","pheed":"My stomach being hurting all day","datetime":"1313422390","comments":"0"},{"user_id":"9","pheed_id":"11","pheed":"My stomach being hurting all day","datetime":"1313422390","comments":"0"},{"user_id":"9","pheed_id":"10","pheed":"Thank God for stackoverflow.com ","datetime":"1313358605","comments":"0"},]
```

But i cant seem to access it with jquery

Comment: do you need that comma at the end

Comment: How are you trying to access it with jQuery?

Comment: As suggested, the comma at the end is breaking the json decoding.  Also, as suggested in the asker by @derekerdmann, use json_encode for this, it is what it is meant for.

Comment: Yes, just give your **PHP array** to **json_encode()** function.

Comment: I use json_encode all the time between PHP and javascript.  You should revisit your code and do the same.  No need to wrap your own.

Comment: Yeah to seperate each array of information

Comment: Yeah to seperate each array of information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already voted up @derekerdmann, but thought I would add...

Your code will work, if you change:

```
if($i == count($data)) {
```

to

```
if($i == count($data) - 1) {
```

But, **don't** do that.  If you are just putting everything from each member of the `$data` array into the json, then you should be able to just `json_encode($data)`.  If you are only pulling out certain parts, then build up a secondary array of your filtered data and `json_encode` that instead.

```
function latest_pheeds() {
    if($this->isLogged() == true) {
        $this->load->model('pheed_model');
        $data = $this->pheed_model->get_latest_pheeds();
        $filtered_items = array();
        foreach ($data as $member) {
            $filtered_item = array();
            $filtered_item['user_id'] = $member['user_id'];
            $filtered_item['pheed_id'] = $member['pheed_id'];
            ...
            ...
            $filtered_items[] = $filtered_item;
        }
        echo json_encode($filtered_items);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe the problem rests with the trailing comma at the end of your array.

Rather than try to encode it yourself, use PHP's [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.  It's been tested and verified many, many times, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MrFoh: that is a different issue.  I would suggest setting your headers to indicate that you are returning JSON.